# Combine and graph data in Excel with non-matching X values

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have 2 sets of data in tabular form, say (x,y) and (x,z). Both sets share variable x, but for each set x has a different increment (see example). I would like to generate a graph (y,z) without using VBA or third party interpolation apps. Thank you in advance for your responses.

Example:

Dataset 1:

```
x: 1, 2, 3

y: 1, 2, 7
```

Dataset 2:

```
x: 0.3, 0.6, 0.9, 1.2, 1.5, 1.8, 2.1, 2.4, 2.7, 3.0

z: 1,   2,   3,   4,   5,   6,   7,   8,   9,   10
```

Comment: Just to clarify, are you looking to graph Y and Z in relation to X, as described in Máté Juhász's answer, or Y vs. Z (without X, where one would become the X and the other the Y for graphing purposes)?

Answer (score 1):

You can easily do it with scatter plot:

- Select your first dataset (both x and y values)
- navigate to insert - charts - XY (Scatter)
  *(this can be slightly different depending on your Excel version)*
- insert the chart
- right click on the chart - select data - add new series

  - here select data for horizontal and vertical axis from the second dataset

[image]

Comment: +1 for figuring out what the question was asking.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you want to graph Y vs. Z (without X, where one would become the X and the other the Y for graphing purposes.
I had to do this just now.

1. I made sure both sets are sorted on the *x* value, in separate
   sheets.
2. I took the larger data set (your data set 2).
3. In the third column (the column after your z), top cell, I wrote this formula:
   =arrayformula(vlookup($a$1:$a$10,'other_sheet'!$a$1:$a$3,2,true). Call this column y.
4. I created a chart from columns Z and Y. You may have to switch Z and Y to get the correct series on the X axis.

Notes:

- 'other_sheet' has the smaller data set (your set 1). I don't know what's more
  efficient. I'm assuming that a larger number of VLOOKUPs on a smaller
  data set is more efficient than a smaller number of lookups on a
  larger data set.
- I'm starting both data sets from $a$1,assuming no header rows; you
  can adjust that.